# Creating an annual income field in django models with currency option of all types available in djmoney

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, currency

I have created annual_income field in django-model like this :

`models.py`

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
...

annual_income = MoneyField(
            max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, default_currency="INR"
        )
```

here the default currency has been set to INR. I would like to have the field in such a way that it takes the currency as input, instead of setting it to default 'INR'. 
In the admin page, this field should be displayed such that there is dropdown option for the currencies

Comment: How does your admin.py looks like, are you using default widget

Comment: yes i am using a default widget. my admin.py has list_filter, list_display of the models fields, search_fields.